# Storing a character into video RAM isn't working (in a bootloader)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

hello i started developing simple os that runs on x86_64 cpu
so i wrote a bootsector code like downbelow (i use nasm)
but it doen't work as i expected

i intended display "A" on the top left place(no problem until this part)
then change it to "t" which is first letter of MESSAGE1 string
but 'cl' register doesn't seem to point address of "t"
please check the code line 27~29 i annotated

i try several way to fix this problem

first i checked binary of my code then find the exact address of MESSAGE1
then i accessed that address directly but it's also not worked
second i checked my code whether there is wrong syntax
third i moved MESSAGE1 code to different position to check the position of code affect result
but all of this approach not worked

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x00]

SECTION .text;코드의 성격에따라 적절한 메모리를 사용하게 해줌 .text 섹션은 값 변경이 불필요한 코드에 적합함  

jmp 0x07C0:START

START:
mov ax, 0x7C00;
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 0xB800
mov es, ax

mov si, 0
;------------------- turn screen white  -------------------------------
.SCREENCLEARLOOP:
    mov byte[es:si], 0
    mov byte[es:si+1], 0xF1

    add si, 2
    cmp si, 80*25*2
    jl .SCREENCLEARLOOP
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
mov si, 0
mov di, 0

mov byte[es:di], 'A';line 27
mov cl, byte[ si + MESSAGE1 ];line 28
mov byte[es:di], cl; line 29

jmp $

MESSAGE1: db 'test string', 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

this is result of upper code

[image]

picture downbelow is result of deleting line 28,29

[image]

Comment: An x86-64 in real mode is x86-16, same as older CPUs.  You're not switching the CPU into long mode so this isn't an x86-64 question.

Comment: okay i'll edit that

Comment: `cl` won't point to anything, it's not a pointer.  But it should hold an `e` from `[si + MESSAGE1]` = `[1 + MESSAGE1]`.

Comment: Does the 'A' actually appear? (Very short, unless you are running this step by step.)

Comment: yes i checked it please wait i'll show you that

Comment: i uploaded new picture that prove 'A' actually appear pls check this

Comment: to  Peter Cordes >> cl seems like hoding nothing because when i display cl on screen A just change into blank rather than a letter so i think cl hold not intended data

Comment: You're initialising `ds` with 7C00h where it should be 7C0h.

Comment: You can notify people when you reply with @ username, like @Dotori.  (You get notified anyway because we're commenting under your answer, but I didn't see your replies until just now.)  Anyway, yes, ECM and I both spotted your bug at the same time.  7C00 is the linear address, so 7C0 is the segment register value you need.  You're jumping to it correctly to set CS, but you're using the wrong value to set DS.

Comment: @ecm thank you soooo much !!! you saved me

Comment: You can and should use a debugger so you can single-step your bootloader.  When you see CL get some random value instead of the `t` you expected, that's your clue that DS is probably set wrong.  From just looking at the screen you have to wonder if you're storing the result to the right place or whatever.  You can connect to QEMU as a GDB remote, or use BOCHS which has a built-in debugger that understands segmentation.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you so much! you saved my time

Comment: @PeterCordes what kind of debugger can i use for these kind of developement? now i only depend on console error messages

Comment: GDB can connect to QEMU as a "remote".  Google it.  Or better, use BOCHS instead of QEMU; it has a debugger built-in.  http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html.  It has a GUI or text command interface.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for good informations!  i'll search it